# Get array with JOINed values

Tags: arrays, json, sqlite, join, node-sqlite3

I'm using [SQLite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) on NodeJS and have a database in memory with a relation between `table1` and `table2`. `fk` field in `table2` is `id` in `table1`.

`table1` :

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v1_t1 | v2_t1 |

`table2` :

| id | value1 | fk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v1_t2 | 1 |
| 2 | v2_t2 | 1 |

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.fk=t1.id WHERE t1.id=1;
```

Result is :

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value1: v1_t2,
    fk:1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value1: v2_t2,
    fk:1
  }
]
```

But I want :

```json
[
  {
    fk: 1,
    value1: "v1_t1",
    value2: "v2_t1",
    result: [
      {
        id: 1,
        value1: "v1_t2",
        fk: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value1: "v2_t2",
        fk: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is this possible or should I use a non-relational database?

Comment: You posted the results that you get and your expected results as JSON objects which is not what the query returns. The query returns rows in tabular format and it resembles your expected results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3eb3aa46a8a5e2ae1bb41be46599abbb

Comment: And there is a way (using [JSON extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) or whatever) to get desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQLite's [JSON1 Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) functions:

```
SELECT json_object(
           'fk', t2.fk, 
           'value1', t1.value1, 
           'value2', t1.value2,
           'result',  
           json_group_array(json_object('id', t2.id, 'value1', t2.value1, 'fk', t2.fk))           
       ) col
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.fk = t1.id 
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f9266213702b57af64b285aa0a4ad616).